# How to remove Windows from Grub menu?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows

My setup is GnomeShell Remix 12.04 and Windows 7 dual boot. Now everything works fine, however, I rarely ever boot Windows and I would like to remove the Windows entry from my Grub menu completely and remove the recovery and memtest as well. That way, I hit power, wait a few seconds and I have my login screen, but if I ever get the urge to play simcity, or WOW, or anything else that runs better in Windows 7, then I insert USB, reboot, select Windows 7 and away I go.

Is this at all possible; I'm sure it must be, but I'm just not sure how to go about it. I'm ok with terminal, so I'm not scared to have a go, so any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There is an easier way, Why don't you disable the grub menu ? and make the grub boots to 12.04 automatically. and when you want the grub menu to appear hold the shift button after rebooting and voala

Comment: possible duplicated: [How to remove or hide the GRUB boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/18775/62483)

Comment: thanks for that, Id never thought of doing that, but will definately use that option, just curiosity though, IS there a way of doing it with the USB option, would make a nifty security measure, ie, cant boot into an OS without skills unless you have a USB or something (Keep housemates from using my PC when Im not home.)

Comment: @bilbs84 That should be posted as a new question. It won't get answered hare in comments section. Thanks!