# Boot into Ubuntu without GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2

Finally, I decided to go down the Ubuntu route and hit the first problem. It is not a big problem but more like a convenient feature!

I have no experience in Linux at all and I need a help.

I have re-formatted my HP Net book and loaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Everything went as planned except this small issue! GRUB gets loaded first and I cannot workout how to not load GRUB at the boot time? There is no other OS on the netbook. Hard drive was reformatted

---

I am having issue. Attempted to apply the boot-repair suggestion and got following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
bhavesh@CNU93862F9:~$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
Reading package lists...
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair
```

When I try the 3rd solution, again similar error. It is failing to fetch packages?

Comment: Please don't "answer" your question to request feedback. Only use answer for actual answers. Use [edit] to update and add information to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove or hide the GRUB boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18775/how-to-remove-or-hide-the-grub-boot-menu)

Answer (score 3):

GRUB will be there even if you like it or not. Believe me, its there for a good purpose, for example, if your system fails to boot, you can go into the recovery from the GRUB.

But i f you dont want to see the GRUB screen at all, you can do the following.

We need to edit the grub configuration file. Type the following command into terminal

> gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

This will open up geditor to edit the grub file. Search for `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` and change it to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`.

***You should really consider changing it to a smaller time like 3 or 4 because changing it to 0 will result in the GRUB screen not visible at all, and in case you run into issues, it will be a pain to rectify.***

Save the file and close geditor.

Then type `sudo update-grub` and reboot system.

Comment: I haven't tried setting 0 but: "If then you need to change to Recovery mode in some instance just press ESC" according to http://askubuntu.com/a/18777/40581

Comment: I do not suggest changing timeout to 0, only because then it can be very difficult to get to grub menu when you do want it. I use 3 sec so I have time to press escape(UEFI) or shift key(BIOS) when booting to get menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem:  Grub is the boot loader for Linux and will always be present at boot time, prior to starting Ubuntu.  You can set the Grub menus not to show, which sounds like what you want.

There are several ways to edit and update Grub - since you are new to Linux, I'd recommend a graphical tool called Grub-customizer:  Open a terminal and type the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers. I am having issues, guessing something is not set up?