# How to Speed Up Booting Time ? (Bypass Grub)

Tags: boot, grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 as my Default and only OS.
Whenever I boot up, A Grub Menu Appears and I need to choose a option manually.
Since every time my only option will be 'Ubuntu'
Therefore I want that My Laptop should directly boot into Ubuntu without asking it.

Is there a way to speed up this process and disable Grub?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry) and [How to remove or hide the GRUB boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18775/how-to-remove-or-hide-the-grub-boot-menu)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot disable GRUB.  What you can do though, is alter the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT` in the **/etc/default/grub** file so that the system doesn't wait for you to select something.  In a terminal execute the following commands:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Find the line containing **GRUB_TIMEOUT=** and change the value to **0**.  Save the file and execute:

`sudo update-grub`

for the changes to take effect.  You will never see the GRUB menu again.

I have to warn you though that doing this will result in you having to keep <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed while booting, if you need to access the GRUB menu for any reason.