# Why is my computer turning on to this screen?

Tags: 16.04

My computer was fine until I restarted it. Now it turns on to a screen that says: gnu grub 
Advanced options
Memory test....

Comment: This usually happens after a forced shutdown or a power outage. I hope the computer is still fine, and seeing the Grub menu is the only thing you have to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. The GRUB menu provides options for booting into different operating systems (if installed), and/or different versions of the GNU Linux kernel (if installed).

To prevent the GRUB menu from being displayed, see the [related solution presented here](https://askubuntu.com/a/18777/32664), which will have you make some changes to the grub configuration called, appropriately, `grub`.

Let us know if you have any questions about following that procedure.