# Menu shows up during boot after update to kernel 4.4.0-109-generic

Tags: kernel

After installing the new kernel yesterday, Ubuntu 16.04 starts with an additional screen containing a choice of Ubuntu, Ubuntu options, and memory test. How can I delete it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove or hide the GRUB boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18775/how-to-remove-or-hide-the-grub-boot-menu)

Answer (score 1):

The screen you are referring to is called grub. It's necessary in case of a multi-boot system, but it could be useful to determine and solve some issues on your system.

You cannot delete but you can hide it. To do this:

Open a terminal from inside your system and digit

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>, you will be requested the admin password, insert it and press <kbd>Return</kbd> again. The file at the path specified will open in your terminal.

Find the parameter

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=[Any value]
```

and change it to

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

If the parameter `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` would have a value different from `0` change it to `0` too.

Save your edited file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Then, always in the terminal run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

At the next reboot you will not be able to see Grub screen.

Comment: I am little surprised because I have only Ubuntu 16 with the newest generic. I've changed GRUB-TIMEOUT to 0 and it's better now.

Comment: But with grub you could boot the system loading the previous kernel. Anyway, if you find the answer useful, don't forget to vote it up. thanks

Comment: @MKay Surrounding keyboard keys with `<kbd>` and `</kbd>` makes them look like keyboard keys in your answers.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex, thanks I'll bear in mind for the next posts!

Comment: @ŁukaszBatek, I intended mark as accepted, sorry!