# Not Dual Boot So Why Does GRUB Load?

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

This Ubuntu 21.04 PC never had dual boot, yet GRUB loads when I press F12 to get to the boot choices. I am trying to boot from DVD but can’t seem to get beyond GRUB which does not have the choice to boot to DVD. Do I just uninstall GRUB or is there some other way to deactivate it?

Even though the BIOS has the DVD as the first boot device, GRUB still seems to take over so the only way to boot to the media was to completely remove the hard drive from the boot choices. This is something I’ve never ever had to do in decades of PC work!

The mystery that I am asking about is that F12 typically opens the BIOS boot menu and GRUB never appeared until I used F12 the first time but now F12 brings up GRUB every time.

Comment: Is your goal to avoid seeing the grub menu? Actually deactivating grub may have effects beyond those you seem to envision.  If you just want to hide it, see https://askubuntu.com/q/18775/243321

Comment: If you want boot from DVD, then you need to go into the BIOS (or UEFI) to change from using the default boot method.

Comment: The F12 boot menu is normally the UEFI/BIOS boot menu, not grub. What brand/model system?

Comment: I appended my question to respond to these comments.

Comment: Does this DVD boot in another system?  Or have you tried to boot to a USB or another DVD on this system?  Normally when BIOS won't boot to a drive is probably because the device isn't setup properly to boot from it.  I don't use UEFI on my systems at home and I cannot boot to UEFI created DVDs, or vice versa.

Comment: It will boot to the DVD if I entirely disable HD booting. However, no longer an issue as I put in a different boot HD when nothing I did would keep the hard drive accessible and with the boot drive change, it no longer goes to GRUB.

Comment: I found the problem with the boot DVD (booting to external devices was disabled in the BIOS and, as it’s an internal drive, that seems odd) and it now loads but only to a black screen with cursor. Checking to see if any BIOS settings might be blocking it but have found none so far.